# php in href and iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have found lots of help on this site through the search option but I am totally confused by my latest problem. I think it is a punctuation problem but just cannot find it.

I have an image that is also a link to change an iframe, it is also a selector for a form radio button. However the link in the iframe I want to be taken from a php variable.

I have got the whole thing working up until I wanted to add the php variable. (I got it working with an iframe link manually entered instead of the the variable.

```
</p><p>
   <input style="position: absolute;left:-9999px;" type="radio" name="size" id="A1" />
   <label for="A1">
      <a href="canvas_size.php?width=32&height=22&name=test.jpg"target="iframe_a">
         <img src="/Site_images/A1.png" alt="A1" style="display: inline-block;cursor: pointer;padding: 3px;" alt="A1" />
   </label>
```

The iframe now points to:-

```
www.mydomain.com/<?php=%27$filename%27%20?>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HnXFj/2/

Comment: Your html code is not valid.

Comment: Cheers for the help guys, in the end I got the code to work:-
<input style="position: absolute;left:-9999px;" type="radio" name="size" id="A0" />
<label for="A0"><a href="canvas_size.php?width=45&height=32&name=<?php echo $filename ?>" target="iframe_a"><img src="/Site_images/A0.png" alt="A0" style="display: inline-block;cursor: pointer;padding: 3px;" alt="A0" /></label>